# Pandas format symbols xlsx

Tags: python, pandas, xlsx

I need a `%`symbol on my xlsx. I apply `format2 = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '0%'})` but with that my numbers are multiplicated for `100` and I don´t want it! I need only add the `%`symbol

xlsx data:

```
1.72
```

format2:

```
172%
```

format I need:

```
1.72%
```

Comment: i think the easiest way is to convert `1.72` to string `'1.72%'` on Pandas side. Alternatively you can divide your numbers by 100 and use `%` format...

Comment: How can I divide all my Column?? @MaxU

Comment: that's easy: `df.select_dtypes('number').div(100.)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First divide your numerical columns by 100:

```
df.loc[:, df.dtypes.apply(lambda c: np.issubdtype(c, np.number))] = \
     df.select_dtypes('number').div(100.)
```

alternatively:

```
cols = df.columns[df.dtypes.apply(lambda c: np.issubdtype(c, np.number))]
df[cols] /= 100.
```

now you can use your `%` format in Excel